# why I get __init__.py problems when using selenium webdrivers chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im working on a project and have this as code:

```py
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print(driver.current_url)
```

but i get an error and i dont know how to fix it, well mutle tracebacks to error i think, here is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ytty\PycharmProjects\test hack\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\ytty\PycharmProjects\test hack\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\ytty\PycharmProjects\test hack\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .service import Service
  File "C:\Users\ytty\PycharmProjects\test hack\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 21, in <module>
    class Service(service.Service):
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.common.service' has no attribute 'Service'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

can anyone help?

Comment: and why is the code thing so weird?

Comment: It seems like something has gone wrong in your virtual environment install. What is in `C:\Users\ytty\PycharmProjects\test hack\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py`? It should be the implementation of class Service.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: Personally, I'd just create a fresh virtual environment and reinstall the packages I need.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

This way it will automatically download the optimal ChromeDriver version on your cache and use it every time you need. Also the experimental part helps to avoid some error that might appear due to driver bugs